# UIImagePickerController | Photo Library Appearing But Selection Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController working fine with camera mode, but not in library mode. When Photo Library is presented, you can scroll and select cancel, but when tapped, albums are not selectable. Been trying to figure this out for about an hour now, but it's not working.

XCode 8.3.3 | iOS 10.3.2

Added proper privacy needed, and below is my simple presentation code.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
// Opens Photo Library
    func openPhotoLibrary() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIAlertController.presentWith(title: "Error".localize(), message: "The photo library can not be accessed at this time.".localize(), on: self)
        }
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        guard currentImage != "left" else {
            leftImage = image
            leftImageView.image = image
            return
        }

        guard currentImage != "right" else {
            rightImage = image
            rightImageView.image = image
            return
        }

        guard currentImage != "front" else {
            frontImage = image
            frontImageView.image = image
            return
        }
    }
```

[image]

LINK TO PROBLEM: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsKA994Sg88&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @dfd The photo library is opening, but the selection of an album doesn't do anything. I'm able to scroll and cancel, but unable to do anything else.

Comment: @dfd The photo library is opening so we know that the if statement succeeds. The issue is that none of the albums or photos are selectable inside of the library.

Comment: @dfd `class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {`

Comment: @dfd Updated the question

Comment: (1) Is the `didFinishPIckingMediaWithInfo` being hit? (2) Your code won't do anything if `currentImage` is not "left", "right" or "front". Is that what's happening?

Comment: It's not being hit, because I can't select any albums/images in the viewcontroller when it presents the albums. @dfd

Comment: @dfd Added a video of the problem, so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @dfd Removing the guard statements doesn't change anything. Let me try the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE.

Comment: @dfd didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo isn't even being called btw.

Comment: @dfd I'm not able to drill down. I'm tapping on the screen, and nothing is happening. That's the exact issue I'm having. The cancel button works, and the scroll works, but tapping on the album doesn't work. I need to be able to tap the album to select an image.

Comment: @dfd Ok! Thank you for your help by the way!!

Comment: I am confused about one thing that when you select a album, it will show whole images in your album. But in your video it seems you click cancel button but not select any album? It not even show all images.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The issue was resulting from an extension of UIView we use to dismiss the keyboard. Many of you may have seen it before.

```
extension UIView {
  // Dismisses Keyboard
  open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

The solution is simple, just add `super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)` before `self.endEditing(true)` and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if you were not selecting but you are. The problem is that you need to dismiss the image picker within the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
           imagePicker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```